# SQL to return the rownum of a specific row? (using Oracle db)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, rowid

In Oracle 10g, I have this SQL:

```
select dog.id as dogId from CANINES dog order by dog.codename asc
```

which returns:

```
id
--
204
203
206
923
```

I want to extend this query to determine the oracle rownum of a dog.id in this resultset.

I have tried

```
select rownum from 
(select dog.id as dogId from CANINES dog order by dog.codename asc) 
where dog.id=206
```

But this does not work out very well (it returns 1 no matter which dog.id I match on).  I was expecting to get back 3.

Thanks for your help!

---

*Notes*

http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56asktom.html

I am pretty sure I do not need to use rowid

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect what you want is to use an analytic function (RANK, `DENSE_RANK`, or `ROW_NUMBER`), i.e.

```
SELECT rnk
  FROM (select dog.id as dogId,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY dog.codename ASC ) rnk
          from CANINES dog )
 WHERE dogId = 206
```

If the ID column in the CANINES table were not unique, RANK, `DENSE_RANK`, and `ROW_NUMBER`) would treat ties differently.

If you want to do this solely with ROWNUM,

```
SELECT rn
  FROM (
        SELECT dogId, rownum rn
          FROM (select dog.id as dogId
                  from CANINES dog 
                 order by dog.codename ASC) inner
       ) middle
 WHERE dogId = 206
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're after the unique identifier of each row in the table you need ROWID, not ROWNUM.

ROWNUM is a pseudocolumn that can change each time a bit of SQL is executed (it's worked out at query time)

Comment: I want to know the sorted row number for a given id in my query, so I guess I want rownum.  Thanks.

Comment: Seriously, stick to the OP. You can answer what you wanted them to ask after you deal with the OP.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

**Answer**

```
SELECT dog1.DogID, dog1.DogName, COUNT(*) AS rownumber
FROM #ids dog1, #ids dog2
WHERE dog2.DogName <= dog1.DogName
GROUP BY dog1.DogID, dog1.DogName
ORDER BY dog1.DogName
```

**Results**

```
DogID       DogName    rownumber
----------- ---------- -----------
204         Dog 1      1
203         Dog 2      2
206         Dog 3      3
923         Dog 4      4
```

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE #ids (DogID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, DogName varchar(10) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO #ids (DogID, DogName) VALUES (204, 'Dog 1')
INSERT INTO #ids (DogID, DogName) VALUES (203, 'Dog 2')
INSERT INTO #ids (DogID, DogName) VALUES (206, 'Dog 3')
INSERT INTO #ids (DogID, DogName) VALUES (923, 'Dog 4')
```

Comment: Regrettably, I cannot substantively change my original query (as you do in your answer) because it is auto-generated by another process.

Comment: Ah, then this approach will not work.  But you should be able to use the "rownum" feature in Oracle to get the same pseudo rownumber.

Comment: You can do the same thing much easier in Oracle.
"select dogID, DogName, rownum from #ids order by DogName"
 returns the same result as the group-by query, but will perform much better.

Comment: @Beach, are you a long time SQL Server or MySql guy? I believe they didn't have rownum until recently. Hitting the table twice is a huge performance hit compared with just once.

Comment: @Mark True, I primarily use MSSQL.  But I also try and use ANSI-standard SQL when possible. "rownum" is not portable. The hit may not be that big depending on how many rows there are and if the table is properly indexed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this, it would be best to alter the table and add a sequence. This could get sticky if you intend to delete rows. Where, perhaps a better practice would be to use a status column or and start-end-date motif to decide which rows are active and should be returned.